# F11 in kiosk mode in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen, kiosk-mode

is <kbd>F11</kbd> key disabled in -kiosk mode in Google chrome? I am developing a web application, not chrome extension but my target browser is only Google Chrome. After developing 90% of the app, just now I got stuck in this issue, i.e. if I run Chrome in -kiosk mode, I get nothing for <kbd>F11</kbd> keydown!!!!

I read the same observation [here](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/internet-explorer-tips/internet-explorer-full-screen/) as well.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering the question myself, because perhaps the stage is not clear; I'm talking about running chrome in **kiosk mode**, not normal mode. Anyway **keydown** event is absorbed by chrome, however **keyup** can still be captured in this situation. I hope that this helps someone if they encounter the same challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Isn’t there any way of changing hockeys in chrome? assign to full screen mode other key and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the key, but can you just not use the fullScreen API?  document.body.webkitRequestFullScreen should take the user full screen on any keyboard or mouse interaction (that you choose).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> exits the -kiosk mode..

Comment: The reason for my answer was to show you how to exit the kiosk mode since f11 does not work.